# Xcode show image in UIImageView from PHP Echo MySQL BLOB

Tags: php, xcode

With PHP I am returning image blob from MySQL and straight way Echo it.
In Xcode I get it:

`NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];` This is OK!

To show in UIImageView I am trying this:

```
cardImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
```

If I make `Nslog(@"%@", result);` there are lot of these:

`<efbbbf89 504e470d 0a1a0a00 00000d49 48445200 0001f400 00014e08 02000000 ffe578ce 00000019 74455874 536f6674`.................. It meands that there are data!

Question is how to show image from straght way PHP blob echo to UIImageViev.image ?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should try to see if your image was successfully built :

```
cardImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
if (cardImage.image == nil){
    NSLog(@"image wasn't created");
} else {
    NSLog(@"image was created successfully");
}
```

If it was successful then your problem is coming from displaying the image.
If it wasn't successful then your problem is coming from the data in result. The imageWithData method wasn't able to build an image from the data you got.

---

edit : Then it may come from the encoding of characters.

Comment: Thanks for advise. NSlog says - image wasn't created:( Its mean that data from PHP Echo cant be interpreted as image data in UIImageView? Is there some suggestion how to manage it?

Comment: There was problems with PHP service. PHP file was saved with headers - be sure to save plain UTF-8 file encoding!